# How to merge similar js functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax

My problem is that I don't know how to merge those similar functions, I'm pretty sure there is some way to cut it to one function. **1099** and **1100** is id of game. **ajax_query** is my function which runs an ajax query with given parameters.

```
$('#away1099').click(function ()
{
    if ($( "#home1099" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'home', 'remove', 'home', 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#away1099" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'away', 'remove', 'away');
    }
    else
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'away', 'add', 'away');
    }
    return false;
});

$('#home1099').click(function ()
{
    if ($( "#away1099" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'away', 'remove', 'away', 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#home1099" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'home', 'remove', 'home');
    }
    else 
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'home', 'add', 'home'); 
    }
    return false;
});


$('#away1100').click(function ()
{
    if ($( "#home1100" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'home', 'remove', 'home', 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#away1100" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'away', 'remove', 'away');
    }
    else
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'away', 'add', 'away');
    }
    return false;
});

$('#home1100').click(function ()
{
    if ($( "#away1100" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'away', 'remove', 'away', 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#home1100" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'home', 'remove', 'home');
    }
    else 
    {
        ajax_query(1100, 'home', 'add', 'home'); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Drive this on the basis of class attribute :**

for example:

if there are 2 divs like below:

```
 <div id="away1099" />
 <div id="away2000" />
```

and then add some class to it :

```
   <div id="away1099"  class="away" />
   <div id="away2000"  class="away" />
```

then bind jquery event to class selectors:

```
$('.away').click(function ()
{
   // your logic
});
```

Comment: I just love the simplicity of this solution. JQuery to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code to a single function that accepts some kind of "type" parameter and maybe one more variable. Based on this "type" amend the particular code parts in the function.

Something like this maybe...

```
var myTypes = {home: 1, away: 2};

function doStuff(type, num)
    var mySelector1;
    switch (type){
        case myTypes.home:
            mySelector1 = "#home" + num;
            break;
        case myTypes.away:
            mySelector1 = "#away" + num;
            break;
    }
    // and so on...
    // change what's needed based on type..
    if ($( mySelector1 ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'home', 'remove', 'home', 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#away1099" ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'away', 'remove', 'away');
    }
    else
    {
        ajax_query(1099, 'away', 'add', 'away');
    }
}

$('#away1099').click(function ()
{
    doStuff(myTypes.away, '1099');
    return false;
});

$('#home1099').click(function ()
{
    doStuff(myTypes.home, '1099');
    return false;
});
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$('#away1099,#home1099,#away1100,#home1100').click(function ()
{
   $elem = $(this);
   var number = $elem.attr("id").substr(5),
       word = $elem.attr("id").slice(1,5);

   if ($elem.hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
   {
        ajax_query(number, word, 'remove', word, 1);
   }
   else
   {
        ajax_query(number, word, 'add', word);
   }
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start.

```
function update(id, action, opposite)
{
    if ($( "#"+action+id ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(id, action, 'remove', action, 1);
    }
    else if ($( "#"+opposite+id ).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" ))
    {
        ajax_query(id, opposite, 'remove', opposite);
    }
    else
    {
        ajax_query(id, opposite, 'add', opposite);
    }

}

$('#away1099').click(function ()
{
    update(1099, "away", "home");
    return false;
});

$('#home1099').click(function ()
{
    update(1099, "home", "away");
    return false;
});

$('#away1100').click(function ()
{
    update(1100, "away", "home");
    return false;
});

$('#home1100').click(function ()
{
    update(1100, "home", "away");
    return false;
});
```

After you can iterate for the bind('click') in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

I would change the HTML slightly to take advantage of data attributes and remove unnecessary IDs. Assuming the clickable elements are buttons for the sake of argument:

Add a `data-type` and `data-number` and change the ID to a class:

```
<button class="gamebutton" data-type="away" data-number="1099">Away 1099</button>
<button class="gamebutton" data-type="home" data-number="1100">Home 1100</button>
```

Set up the function:

```
function gameButtonClick() {

  // get the type and the number from the data attributes
  var type = $(this).data('type');

  // get the opposite type for use later
  var otherType = type === home ? 'away' : 'home';

  // because we need the number value as an integer we need to parse it to one
  var number = parseInt($(this).data('number'), 10);

  if ($(this).hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" )) {

    // and you can use the new type/number variables throughout the function
    ajax_query(number, type, 'remove', type, 1);
  } else if ($('button[data-type="' + otherType + '"][data-number="' + number + '"]').hasClass( "table-bets-choosen" )) {
    ajax_query(number, type, 'remove', type);
  } else {
    ajax_query(number, type, 'add', type);
  }
  return false;
}

// Clicking on a button of a certain class calls the function
$('.gamebutton').click(gameButtonClick);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/85bBX/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Save the two(or more) values in a array and iterate through it:

```
var array = new Array("away1099", "home1099", "away1100", "home1100");  
for (a = 0; a < 4; a++) {

    $(array[a]).click(function() {
        //i would suggest you redo some of the functions otherwise the solution for your problem will be equaly "bad"
    });
}
```

I wanted to write down how you would have to do it exactly in your case but m8 you really need to go through what exactly you are doing here because those function calls seem so redundant that you could make them much nicer and easier to work with.